# How to configure KrakenD gateway with a reference token? (not jwt)

Tags: identityserver4, api-gateway, krakend

I'm trying to put at place Krakend in my current architecture (micro services architecture), I have already an IDP (Identity Server).

KrakenD is able to self validate the jwt token, the problem is that for some use cases we are not using jwt token, we are using a [reference token](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/reference/).

Is there any plugin to allow KrakendD to retirnve the token detail from my Identity Server?
Some token meta datas are needed (client id, user id...) this will allow me to for example implementing a monetization mecanism or configuring the Rate limit per client id.

What is the better approach to have at the same time KrakenD and Reference Token?

I didn't try anything, I'm wondering how to do using KrakenD Apigateway

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no plugin that supports token introspection, but you could implement your own if you have Go knowledge: https://www.krakend.io/docs/extending/writing-plugins/

Comment: It was my conclusion as well, I'll not introduce a new techo/language that no one knows at the company.
In the other hand it's not usual to use the reference token and from technical point of view I don't see any inconvenience to go back to jwt token (the only constraint is the size, if I'm not wrong we should not exeed 8kb).